# Adaptative non uniform font-size within same div

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to go from *this*:

[image]

To *this*:

[image]

That is **non uniform** font-size within the same div.
In this example the word "conversation" has been scaled down to the div width. But the rest of the text keep the default font size.

I've tried using css clamp() function, but i couldn't get the desired result.

I have read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67198708/adaptative-font-size-within-same-div-in-css) but it doesnt answer if it's possible to obtain **adaptive** scaling within the same div.
As for my understanding using vw affects the entired div content uniformly.

Comment: Sounds like you need to use javascript. Check if your title overflows the div and then adjust font size.

Comment: There’s jquery bigText that will do what you want. Also checkout fitText

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is separate your `title` tags into `span` tags.

```css
.one {
  font-size:38px;
}
.two {
  font-size:20px;
  }
```

```html
<h1>
<span class = "one">Hello</span>
<span class = "two">World</span>
</h1>
```

Comment: i retrieve my titles from my database. i need to automate scaling, as titles have different lengths.

Comment: if we can test the length of each word then maybe we can apply a new span to those words.